# Number of index 3 normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group given by $\langle a, b, c | aba^{-1}b^{-1}c^2 = 1 \rangle$.

How can I compute the number of index 3 normal subgroups of this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Index $3$ normal subgroups are determined by group homomorphisms $G\to\Bbb Z_3$ (to the $3$ element group). 
   [Note that if we compose an $f:G\to\Bbb Z_3$ with the nontrivial automorphism $x\mapsto -x$ of $\Bbb Z_3$, we get the *same kernel*.]
2. Group homomorphisms $G\to H$ are described by *evaluating* the generators $a,b,c$ in $H$ so that the relations hold.

Comment: The possible image of $a,b,c$ is $\{0,1,2\} \times \{0,1,2\} \times \{0,1,2\}$, so by checking that if $a+b-a-b+c+c = 0$, so the possible pair is $\{(a,b,c) : c=0\}$, a set of 9 elements. Am I right?

Comment: Well, $\Bbb Z_3$ has a nontrivial automorphism, composing this with any $G\to\Bbb Z_3$ gives the same kernel. This means that most normal subgroups were probably counted twice..

Comment: (The pair of  e.g. the  morphism $(a,b,c)\mapsto (1,1,0)$ is $\ (a,b,c)\mapsto (-1,-1,0)$ where $-1=2$ in $\Bbb Z_3$.)